# How to get request user id in Django Serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting `KeyError`: `'request'` while i want to get the current user `id` through user request.
I tried something like this:  `validated_data['user_id'] = CarOwnerCarDetails.objects.get(user_id=self.context['request'].user.id)` but it's throwing me `KeyError`.

How to get the current user `id` through request in serializers?

 if any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance my friends.

models :

```
class CarOwnerCarDetails(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class GetQuotes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CarOwnerCarDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=False, null=True)
```

serializers :

```
class ShopGarageGetQuoteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    subject = CharField(error_messages={'required':'subject key is required', 'blank':'subject is required'})
    user_id = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = GetQuotes
        fields= ['user_id', 'subject']      
      
    def create(self,validated_data):
        subject        = validated_data['subject']
        validated_data['user_id'] = CarOwnerCarDetails.objects.get(user_id=self.context['request'].user.id)

        quotes_obj = GetQuotes.objects.create(
            subject=subject,
            user_id=validated_data['user_id']
            ) 
        return validated_data
```

views.py :

```
class ShopGarageGetQuoteAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        data           = request.data
        serializer =  ShopGarageGetQuoteSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'success' :'True','message' : 'Quotes send successfully','data' : serializer.data},status=200)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=400)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as is written in the [Official Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) the user information (if the Authentication framework is correctly setup) is available using `request.user`

In your View you have to pass it using the [serializer's context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

```py
class ShopGarageGetQuoteAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        data  = request.data
        context = {'request': request} 
        serializer =  ShopGarageGetQuoteSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'success' :'True','message' : 'Quotes send successfully','data' : serializer.data},status=200)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=400)
```

For Generic Views/Viewsets the standard context contains 'request', 'view' and 'format' but in a standard APIView you have to pass it manually